# react-router-dom - add param to index url but accept page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, path, routes, react-router

Currently I have the following code:

```
<Router history={history}>
  <div>
    <Route exact path="/:id?" component={Container1} />
    <Route path="/component2/ component={Container2} />
  </div>
</Router>
```

"localhost:3000" returns Container 1 (as expected).

"localhost:3000/123" returns a different view of Container 1 (as expected).

However when I navigate to "localhost:3000/component2/" it appears along side Component 1.

My question is how can I make the index route take both an id but still accept a component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to wrap these two routes in [Switch](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch), like this:

```
<Router history={history}>
  <div>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/component2/" component={Container2} />
      <Route exact path="/:id?" component={Container1} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 1):

React Router handles the routes with the same priorities as in which order did they get defined. So in your case it should be

```
<Router history={history}>
  <div>
    <Route path="/component2/ component={Container2} />
    <Route exact path="/:id?" component={Container1} />
  </div>
</Router>
```

Comment: /component2/ still renders both Container1 and Container2 ?

Comment: It needed to be wrapped in a Switch statement.